# Add color to the last-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

```css
.d1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.d1>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.d1>div>span:last-child {
  color: green;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.d1>div>span:nth-child(2n) {
  color: red;
}

.d1>div>span:nth-child(2n+1) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>+3</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>+6</span>
    <span>11</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>7</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above example, I am trying to implement an addition for two different columns that is executed with javascript code. The row is from bottom to the top. The last number to be shown must be higher `font-size` and with green `color`. This `font-size` works for both columns but not the `color`. I add the `color: green` inside the `span:last-child` but that does not seem to work... How could I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you can update your CSS code to force the color change on the last element as follows:

```
.d1>div>span:last-child {
  color: green !important;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

(Caution: Using `!important` would override any other styles applied to the element, it is generally considered bad practice to use it unless absolutely necessary)

Answer (score 0):

It's a specificity problem:

> When multiple declarations have equal specificity, the last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity))

Your `last-child` styles are overridden by the odd and even elements styles. To solve this, you can move the `last-child` styles after the odd and even ones:

```css
.d1>div>span:nth-child(even) {
  color: red;
}

.d1>div>span:nth-child(odd) {
  color: blue;
}

.d1>div>span:last-child {
  color: green;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

You can also use the `odd` and `even` keywords to make the code more readable.